# How to create an iterative variable name with mutate in a for loop?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a loop from 1 to 5 and have to essentially create var1 to var5 within the loop. My current code looks something like

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  iris <- iris %>%
    mutate(paste0("var_", i) = Sepal.Length + i)
}
```

However, this returns an error

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  iris <- iris %>%
    mutate(paste0("var_", i) ="
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

How can I dynamically name variables within the mutate statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
for (i in 1:5) {
  iris <- iris %>%
    mutate("{paste0('var_', i)}" := Sepal.Length + i) 
}
```

This uses syntax from the `glue` package to dynamically rename.